FASTAPI Python parametro con contenido de la private-key que falla al fimar un CSR
Estoy intentando codificar en FASTAPI una función para que el endpoint /createCSR, tome por parámetro obligatorios el CN del dominio y la cadena de la private Key en formato PEM.
Cuando en la función recupero el valor de la cadena veo que concatena la private key de esta forma:
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIBVgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAUAwggE8AgEAAkEA3yi53c2imRayg0xK\\ ... odMnzAT9Te1ETQynrA+m83IgYXlBvSkCIQDqJ2/UJnmKsMf/+mvTK8nhDDb9NDp2\\n+E3XH5dF7umaSg==\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n 
En este formato en la url no consigo:

cambiar las cadenas \n por \n y escribir un archivo temporal
o modificar la cadena para que me lo tome en un formato que quedaria asi dentro de un archivo:

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----  MIIBVgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAUAwggE8AgEAAkEA3yi53c2imRayg0xK mIxsKgvUlT8Kbnx0r0Q3ayc8OdfY5kO3GziHC8tqJ+DowStQ30N/arIXK+H3uIvq TR42UQIDAQABAkEAy9ePsCOeWuh4t6aAnUfnpaCY1pt3E+VrUI2ncaGtScdDLGER ... +E3XH5dF7umaSg== -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
¿Cómo debo de manejar el parámetro de query para transformarlo dentro de mi código del primer formato que muestro al segundo?
Lo he intentado hacer con la siguiente líneas de código:
   privateKey="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIBVgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAUAwggE8AgEAAkEA3yi53c2imRayg0xK\\nmIxsKgvUlT8Kbnx0r0Q3ayc8OdfY5kO3GziHC8tqJ+DowStQ30N/arIXK+H3uIvq ... n+E3XH5dF7umaSg==\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n"

   modPK=privateKey.replace("\\n","\n")
'''
; pero la cadena queda:

    -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\MIIBVgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAUAwggE8AgEAAkEA3yi53c2imRayg0xK\mIxsKgvUlT8Kbnx0r0Q3ayc8OdfY5kO3GziHC8tqJ+DowStQ30N/arIXK+H3uIvq\TR42UQIDAQABAkEAy9ePsCOeWuh4t6aAnUfnpaCY1pt3E+VrUI2ncaGtScdDLGER\+CfmZxpI03bYtmYP1b8RFdFmpRxihNR5JTGr4QIhAP8QEd4xumfzyfzsC0Vb1lg/\UzSpKNA92j0ks4YCVISrAiEA3/qlNqUHWPLZgL5ZtWcMNlMsk5qyPhwZatxpLkzc\2PMCIQCB6kh/mWqt6iHW/s/a2yU5O8AA0aylLOwNOrVqK6OrEwIgdWo7+e2BcIu+\odMnzAT9Te1ETQynrA+m83IgYXlBvSkCIQDqJ2/UJnmKsMf/+mvTK8nhDDb9NDp2\+E3XH5dF7umaSg==\-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\

; pero no entiendo como conseguir el modo PEM

